# Closure of the Unit Sphere in the complex plane as the image of a function on the Integers with discrete topology.

Tags: general-topology

> Let [$\mathbb{Z}, \tau $] be a topological space, with $\mathbb{Z}$ being the set of all integer numbers and $\tau$ being the Discrete Topology. With $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$ and $S^1$ being the unit sphere, define  $$ f_\alpha:\mathbb{Z} >\rightarrow S^1\subset\mathbb{C} ~,~ n \mapsto exp(2\pi i n \alpha). $$

$\underline{Question:}$ How can the closure  $\overline{f_\alpha(\mathbb{Z})} \subset S^1$ be characterized? I have made an approach to understand this by myself. Is my conclusion right? Thanks for your help!

$\underline{My~Approach:}$

$\overline{f_\alpha(\mathbb{Z})}$ can be written as the union of the boundary of $f_\alpha(\mathbb{Z})$ with the set of all its inner points $$ \overline{f_\alpha(\mathbb{Z})} =\partial f_\alpha(\mathbb{Z}) ~\cup~\mathring{f_\alpha(\mathbb{Z})},$$
the first of which is empty and the second of which is the set $f_\alpha(\mathbb{Z})$ itself. Thus $$ \overline{f_\alpha(\mathbb{Z})} = f_\alpha(\mathbb{Z}),$$ so that $f_\alpha(\mathbb{Z})$ is a closed subset of $S^1$. I got to this conclusion by thinking about the possible neighbourhoods of an element in the image of $f_\alpha$ in the unit sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conclusion is not right, I'm afraid.

The boundary $\partial f_\alpha(\mathbb{Z})$ is not empty. To see this, note that because $\alpha$ is not rational the function $f_\alpha$ is injective. If you divide $S^1$ into intervals then you can use the pigeonhole principle to show that some interval contains infinitely many $f_\alpha(n)$, and you can use these to construct a sequence without a limit in $f_\alpha(\mathbb{Z})$.

Hint to find the boundary: use the pigeonhole principle as above and the fact that $f_\alpha$ is a homomorphism to show that every open set in $S^1$ contains an element of $f_\alpha(\mathbb{Z})$.

The interior is not $f_\alpha(\mathbb{Z})$. You have to be careful, because after applying $f_\alpha$ you are inside $S^1$, so you are working with its topology, not the discrete topology. This means that singleton sets are not open.

Comment: Thank you. Question: Why is $f_\alpha$ a homomorphism? I don’t know much about abstract algebra, but for example $f_\alpha (1)$ does not equal 1 in the complex numbers.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a group under addition, but $S^1$ is a group under multiplication, and we have $f_\alpha(0)=1$, so that's ok.

Comment: I understand, thank you. One more thing: There has been no information about the topology on $/mathbb{C}$ (or S^1 for that matter). Is there an obvious choice for it, or does it not matter in this case?

Comment: Both $S^1$ and $\mathbb{C}$ have the metric topology